# Inject AngularfireModule in Jasmine

Tags: angular, jasmine, angularfire2

I am trying to write some integration tests using Jasmine, AngularFire2 and Angular. How can I inject and initialize AngularFireModule in order to use an AngularFireDatabase object inside the tests?

Answer (score 1):

Exactly the same way you initialize `AngularFireModule` for your app.

```
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
         AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase, 'my-fancy-app'),
         AngularFireDatabaseModule,
         AngularFireAuthModule
      ],
      declarations: [SomeComponent]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));
```

In reality I found to be a good thing to create dedicated `AppTestingModule`, do all  the imports there and import that module into your tests.